# Is polynomial fitting with least squared error invariant to translation?

Tags: statistics, least-squares

Lets assume I want to estimate some leakage current of a transistor in function of the temperature. For this I will take for example a sixth order polynomial. Will I get different results for the estimated leakage current if I do the fitting (using the least squared error method) and evaluation with the temperature in °C and in K (which basically adds a translation by 273.15 on the x scale)?

I did try it and get a (small) difference when I fit in either °C or K, evaluate the polynomial using the corresponding unit and then translate it to compare the results. The difference is small though, so I am not sure if its just a numerical error.

Comment: Yes, polynomial fitting is invariant to translation, because a translation of a degree-$n$ polynomial is still a degree-$n$ polynomial. However, depending on which polynomial basis you're using, there may be a significant amount of numerical error (the monomial basis $1, x, x^2, \dots, x^n$ is especially ill-conditioned).

Comment: If $p_K(x)$ is the polynomial fit you used in Kelvins, then the one in Celsius should be $p_C(x)\approx p_K(x)-273.15.$

Comment: What do you call a small difference ? Please be specific. The coefficients of the fit should be the same, but the constant term.

Comment: it can be convenient (and more numerically stable) to express your polynomial in powers of $(x-x_{base})$ rather than $x$.  For example, if you're using degree K, you might write your polynomial in powers of $(x-270)$.

Comment: The errors were in the order of magnitude of 10^-21, which is small. But the estimated parameter is also in the order of 10^-14, which then makes a relative error of only 10^-7. Plus the polynomial coefficients are also small, between 10^-6 downto 10^-18.

Comment: It will be invariant (in the sense of getting the same predictions) as long as you include all lower order terms.

Comment: Could you post data points ? I would work with illimited precision.